# ABAQUS scripting: Create a set out of sets

Tags: python, set, abaqus

I have several geometry sets of my model and I want to make a set containing some of these sets. Is there any way I could do this with python? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `SetByBoolean` exactly does that. For example, to create a `set` in assembly by combining two different sets created in part module,

> a=mdb.models[*partName*].rootAssembly
>   a.SetByBoolean(name='*Set-1+Set-2*', sets=(
>       a.allInstances['partName'].sets['Set-1'], 
>       a.allInstances['partName'].sets['Set-2'], ))

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am looking for. Further question, if I created a list out of sets, is there any way I could call it in 'sets=' argument? There are functions like faceArray, edgeArray but I could not find it with sets

Comment: Yes, we can, Just pass the list of sets as tuple.
 `s1 = a.allInstances['partName'].sets['Set-1'], .. ;  
list_of_sets = [s1, s2, ...]; 
a.SetByBoolean(name='temp', sets=tuple(list_of_sets))`

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.